# Passing the dbcontext to the repository: A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following controller, in which I create an instance of the `BadgeAssignmentRepository`. I tried to pass the my dbcontext variable in the declaration of the repository. However I receive `A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property EntryController.db`

I have no idea why my code is wrong. Can someone help me?

Here is the controller:

```
public class EntryController : Controller
{
    public EchoLuMvcDbContext db = new EchoLuMvcDbContext();
    private BadgeAssignmentRepository baRepository= new BadgeAssignmentRepository(db);
    //this db is causing the trouble
```

Here is the repository:

```
public class BadgeAssignmentRepository
{
    public EchoLuMvcDbContext db { get; set; }

    public BadgeAssignmentRepository(EchoLuMvcDbContext context)
    {
        this.db = context;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, you can't access another field from a field initializer. If your BadgeAssignmentRepository needs a reference to your db field, initialize it in your controller's constructor like this:

```
public class EntryController : Controller
{
    public EchoLuMvcDbContext db = new EchoLuMvcDbContext();
    private BadgeAssignmentRepository baRepository;

    public EntryController() {
        baRepository = new BadgeAssignmentRepository(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we get some feedback, @renakre? Please mark as answered or add additional follow up comments. Zombie questions hurt everyone.